# Connection Pooling with Dapper.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dapper

Where can I find more information on connection pooling with Dapper.net?

Comment: connection pooling depends on the ADO.NET provider you use - some have connection-pooling built-in and enabled by default for example...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Dapper doesn't include any such; dapper works *on top of* an open connection, so is beyond the point pooling applies. Your ado.net client may include pooling; SQL server (in ado.net) does, for example.

Comment: This comment suggests that the above is no longer accurate:
"First, Dapper will open the connection if it isn't already open. Second, Dapper just uses ADO.Net which will use connections from the connection pool. Finally Dapper has async methods you could use"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874607/c-dapper-sql-server-and-connection-pooling

Is your answer still correct today?